# How to disable "desktop_notification" messages when using RTM

Tags: slack, slack-api

With RTM connected, when I try to use my account to talk to a bot created by myself with DM, each time I got  3 messages:

"user_typing", "message", "desktop_notification"

Can I suppress "desktop_notification" by applying some settings to my bot?

For me, it seems "message" is good to go.

Comment: Why do you not just ignore events in your script that you do not care about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Slack Real Time Messaging (RTM)](https://api.slack.com/rtm) API does have the concept of subscribing to specific events, **so the answer to your question is no**.

As [Erik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4379151/erik-kalkoken) suggests in his comment, you are best off just ignoring these events in your script -- ideally as early in your logic as possible.

---

One other thing to note is that with the [Event API](https://api.slack.com/events-api) you can subscribe to specific events. There are pros and cons to both the Event/[Web API](https://api.slack.com/web)s and RTM APIs so I mention this out of completeness. The Event API is not a 1:1 supplement for the RTM API in your case from what I can tell for your use case (for example, you'd need to use the Web API for sending a message and Event API for receiving events -- as opposed to just the RTM API as you have now).